# How to delete first row on another Excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I want to remove the first line of the files I open with a Dialog box. Every files has only 1 sheet. So i want to delete every first line on the first sheet of every files opened.

The reason I want to do that is because I export db tables (I tried to not export with header obviously)  and in order to parse them I want to remove this first line which is the header.

On each files open I call my function `Parsing()` where I provide 2 arguments : 2 `Workbook` (one is the Excel I'm using to fire functions, the second is each file found in the folder).

Let me know if I need to provide the first function that open files, but I don't think it is needed because it works fine.

On each file opened I apply the following code :

```sql
Sub Parsing(ByVal wbInit As Workbook, ByVal wb As Workbook)
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    For Each sh In wb.Sheets

        wb.Sheets(1).Rows(1).Delete

        If wb.Name Like "*bpe*" Then
            MsgBox "bpe"
        End If

        If wb.Name Like "*cable*" Then
            MsgBox "cable"
        End If

        If wb.Name Like "*pt*" Then
            MsgBox "pt"
        End If

    Next sh

End Sub
```

The `Msgbox`es are here to test if I actually open files, and it works fine aswell.

However when I re-open the files, the first line is not deleted.

Here is the code that calls the procedure :

```
Sub ouverture_dossier()
    Dim wbInit, wbExtra As Workbook
    Dim dossier, nomFichier As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wbInit = Workbooks(wbInitStr)
    Call Initialisation

    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
    dossier = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    nomFichier = Dir(dossier & "*.xls*")

    Do While nomFichier <> ""
        If Not IsWorkbookOpen(nomFichier) Then
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=dossier & nomFichier
        End If

        Set wbExtra = Workbooks(nomFichier)
        wbExtra.Activate

        Call Parsing(wbInit, wbExtra)

        wbExtra.Close False
        nomFichier = Dir

    Loop

    wbInit.Activate
    Sheets(shBrouillon).Select

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I want to learn from this, so, if possible, explain to me what I'm doing wrong here, or if my approach is lacking insight.

Comment: Actally this `wb.Sheets(1).Rows(1).Delete` deletes the first row in the **first sheet** only. And it does it repeatedly as often as the amount of existing sheets (because of your loop). So if there are 5 sheets in the workbook it deletes 5 rows in the first sheet. • Did you save the workbook after the delete? We cannot see that because you didn't show the other procedure.

Comment: Another vote for saving book. I think it has been omitted

Comment: Actually you cannot delete the first row of an Excel file. You just can delete the first row of a sheet within an Excel file. So you should [edit] your question and be more precice about your wording, to make your question more specific and tell use in which sheet(s) of the workbook you want to delete the first row.

Comment: I've edited with more details and why I try to do that. I hope it is more specific for everyone.

Comment: @LyessD you did not answer my question: *"Did you save the workbook after the delete?"* Please include the code that calls the procedure you show.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ My bad, I add it right now.

Comment: @LyessD So here is your issue: This line `wbExtra.Close False` closes the workbook without saving! So how do you expect that the changes are still there if you reopen it, if you do not save the file after you delete a row? • See my answer below.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ wellc thanks to teach me that  `wbInit` is declared as `Variant`. I have wrong habits I guess.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Ok I understand, i thought when I use the method `.Close` saves file. 
As you can see, I'm not use to code in VBA. But many thanks for explanations !

Comment: @LyessD I posted it as an answer. See below. The issue is that `False` told `.Close` *not* to save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `wbExtra.Close False` closes the workbook without saving! That's why your changes are gone after you re-open the file.

Also note that `Dim wbInit, wbExtra As Workbook` only declares `wbExtra As Workbook` but `wbInit As Variant` you need to specify a type for **every** variable in VBA: `Dim wbInit As Workbook, wbExtra As Workbook`

The following should work (`Sub Parsing` is not needed anymore):

```
Sub ouverture_dossier()
    'every variable needs a type not only the last one!
    Dim wbInit As Workbook, wbExtra As Workbook
    Dim dossier As String, nomFichier As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wbInit = Workbooks(wbInitStr)
    Call Initialisation

    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
    dossier = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    nomFichier = Dir(dossier & "*.xls*")

    Do While nomFichier <> ""
        If Not IsWorkbookOpen(nomFichier) Then
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=dossier & nomFichier
        End If

        Set wbExtra = Workbooks(nomFichier)
        wbExtra.Activate

        wbExtra.Sheets(1).Rows(1).Delete 'thats all you need
        'Call Parsing(wbInit, wbExtra) 'you don't need that anymore

        wbExtra.Close SaveChanges:=True 'you need to save the changes
        nomFichier = Dir

    Loop

    wbInit.Activate
    Sheets(shBrouillon).Select

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It works perfectly ! Thank you for your time and explanations :)

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
Private Sub first_line_removal()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    Next ws

End Sub
```

As a note, the numerical order of the [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) application will not change. What I mean under that: When you open the application *(unless hidden)* the first row will always be enumerated as `[1]`.

Difference here being, the previous first row was deleted and the previous second row was shifted to the now first row.

---

Also as @Pᴇʜ correctly pointed out in the comments, obviously you need to save the workbook before closing it, otherwise the changes will be lost.

```
ThisWorkbook.Save
```

Comment: Yes you were right aswell. I needed to save before closing them

Answer (score 1):

You have a loop that runs through each Sheet *(note, this includes any charts that might be present)* and yet you then attempt to delete the 1st row of sheet 1 each time.

Instead, you should only cycle through the WorkSheets, not Sheets (to exclude any chance of attempting to delete a row from a Chart) and delete row 1 from *that* sheet.

Once you've completed your deletion phase, you should then either Save the file, or Save and Close - upon your preference.

```
Sub Parsing(ByVal wbInit As Workbook, ByVal wb As Workbook)

    Dim sh As Worksheet

    For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
        sh.Rows(1).Delete
    Next sh

    'Delete one of the 2 lines below
    wb.Save         'to leave the file open or
    wb.Close True   'to save and close

End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried also you method, after the one from PeH, and it works perfectly aswell.